# Proof of a stability theorem (Asymptotical stability - dynamical systems)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Question :** How would one prove the following theorem ? If anyone knows the name of it or where I can look it up, please provide a link or a proof.

> **Theorem (Asymptotically unstable stability) :** Consider the dynamical system $x'=f(x)$, where $f: D \to \mathbb R$ a continuously differentiable function at the open interval $D \subset \mathbb R$ with $f(0) = 0$. Show that the point $0\in D$ is asymptotically unstable, if $|f'(0)|<1$.

Comment: This was asked very recently on the site and is quoting an obviously wrong "theorem". Consider $f(x)=-\frac12x$.

Comment: @Did That's an other exam question ... What are they doing to us ??

Comment: I know what “asymptotically stable” is, but what does “asymptotically unstable” even *mean*?

Comment: @HansLundmark Probably means 'completely unstable', i.e. 'asymptotically stable in backwards time'. Works nice for diffeomorphisms and flows, but not for general maps.

Comment: @Evgeny: OK, that makes sense. So the correct statement would have “if $f'(0)>0$” instead. (Or else “$|f'(0)|>1$” if it had been a discrete-time dynamical system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ instead of an ODE.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, it is the correct version for 1d system. For multidimensional system it requires eigenvalues to lie only in open right half-plane or strictly outside of the unit circle, hence the name _completely unstable_ .